# How to save different distributions in a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I'm using Boost C++ for generating random integer samples with different given ranges. Each range correspond to a group. For example, with range (low, high), I can use:
    `boost::mt19937 engine (seed);`
    `boost::bind(boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>(low, high), engine);`

I have 22 such groups (each with different given ranges), and I need to create large number (total 20 millions) of samples from each uniform_int_distribution (corresponding to each group).

For efficiency, I'd like to save the different uniform_int_distributions in say, an array or vector:
    `vector <boost::???> distributions_groups[22];`

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store them by wrapping into `boost::function`:

```
std::vector<boost::function<int (void)>> distributions_groups;
distributions_groups.push_back
(
    boost::bind
    (
        boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>(low, high)
    ,   engine
    )
);
```

Note that all this stuff is available in standard library (given that C++11 standard is supported).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to save off those random number in the `vector`.

I'd use a lambda instead.

```
   boost::mt19937 engine( seed ) ;
   boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(
      min,
      max);

   std::vector < std::vector<int> > 
                 distributions_groups( 22 , std::vector<int>(each_vec_size) );

   auto gen = [distribution, &engine]() { return distribution(engine); } ; 

   // Example :
   for (auto i : distributions_groups) 
   {

      std::generate( begin(i) , end(i) , gen );
      std::cout <<  '\n';
      for (auto j : i) 
      {
         std::cout << j << " ";
      }
   }
```

[<kbd>**Demo Here**</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uJxMdWOzMhOrN6JY)

Comment: I think you misread